# Laravel Mailable with attachment waiting periods

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-5, controller, attachment

I haven't run across this before but have had nothing but successes with Laravel Mailable, so I have no true reason to doubt it now. In my application, I have an attachments section to a record. In that section, I give users the options to select attachment that they would like to mail to a email.

My problem is that as of now, using the below current controller, sometimes the send process can take an incredibly long time (at this time, one example was sent only after 3.67 minutes !!). I understand that this might be partially because of the size, but I'm concerned about this timing and would like to see if there might be a backend alternative (such as queue).

At the moment here is my controller for the command to send to the mailable:

```
public function attachmentsEmail(Request $request){
        $shipment = Shipment::findOrFail($request->shipmentID);
        $attachment = Shipment_Attachment::findOrFail($request->attachmentID);
        $storagePath = Storage::url($attachment->attachmentPath);
        $customMessage = $request->customMessage;
        $email = $request->email;

             Mail::to($email)->send(new shipmentAttachments($shipment, $attachment, $storagePath, $customMessage));  //maybe try to use queue instead of send...        
        return response()->json([
                                    'shipment' => $shipment,
                                    'customMessage' => $customMessage,
                                    'email' => $email
                                ]);
    }
```

We are currently using Windows Server, so while I would like to use queue, I cannot use supervisor to maintain my queues.

However, if there are other suggestions, I'm willing to take them. I'm still relatively new at this and understand that there may be better ways of handling these issues.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a project where we run laravel app on IIS. We had to use a queue to lower latency for the API endpoints where mailables were sent. You're right there is no official stable supervisor for windows that works well with console PHP, but we found AlwaysUp (https://www.coretechnologies.com/products/AlwaysUp/) and ended up running laravel queue under it.
You should also check a smtp server you are using, timing you're talking about seems to much, but depends on exactly attachmens sizes. You can try external mail services like Mailgun.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail - I'll give it a looksee and decide if it would be appropriate (and it likely will be). At the moment, because of concerns I was having with the current smtp and being able to handle the workload, I moved us over to sparkpost for the time being.